# extract one node from a DOM string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a temporary situation where an AJAX call is returning an entire page of HTML instead of just the information or element I need. Until I fix that response (which is very complicated), I would like to accomplish a quick hack if possible. I would like to extract the node I need from the response DOM so that I can insert it into the already-loaded page.

I know that parseHTML will create an array of nodes. Is that the way to go? Can I use jQuery methods like "find()" on it? I'm lost here.

Comment: yes you can.... `$(responseString).find('your-element-selector')` will give you the element

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine if you are using jQuery.

```
$("<div><span>Hello</span></div>").find("span").text();
=> "Hello"
```